# Android internal files seems to disappear after I restart my application

Tags: java, android

I am new to android and currently trying to save a few files in a little "play-around" application I am making to learn, however the files only seem to persist until the application is shut down. When I run:

```
file.exists()
file.isFile()
```

or any similar methods they always return false when the application is restarted.

This is the method I found online to save files:

```
 public void writeToFile(String data, String filePath, Context context){
    File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filePath);

    if(!file.exists()){
        try{
            file.createNewFile();
        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Exception", "File couldn't be created");
        }
    }

    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput(filePath, Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        outputStreamWriter.write(data);
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

I have been googling a lot trying to find a solution but none of them worked. It seems to work when the application is running since I can write and read the files, however at a restart of the application, it cannot find the files. (file.exists() returns false)

Comment: Do you have both the read and write external storage permissions in your manifest?

Comment: You sgould of course also show how you check that the files are not there after restart.

Comment: `file.createNewFile();`. Remove that statement. Its nonsense. OpenFileOutput will create the file.

Comment: `String filePath`. It looks more like a file name.

Comment: `Do you have both the read and write external storage permissions in your manifest? `. @Ben. Nonsense. Not needed for internal memory.

Comment: `String filepath`. Please tell with which value you call that function.

Comment: I would assume you wouldn't need the external permissions for internal use of storage?

As I say earlier in the post it is just a file.exists() that checks if the file exists.

Comment: The string filePath is just the name of which the file is suppose to have in the internal storage. So for example I might create a file with filepath = "file.txt" and when I want to read it I just send in "file.txt"

Answer (score 1):

I just spend an hour tracking down this same bug and it turned out it was because the "Clear User Data" flag was set under "Deployment" in the project properties.  I'm using NVIDIA CodeWorks for Android with Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are attempting to write to internal storage here? If not and you wish to access external storage, I would suggest having a look through the guidance on Android.com below.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

If this *is* internal storage that you are trying to write to, then you need to make sure that you are passing the correct context to the method. For example, if you were running from your MainActivity class and the method was contained within that class, your call would be something along the lines of:

writeToFile("Some data", "aFile.txt", **MainActivity.this**)